# Apache Airflow: Question about Dynamic Tasks and Parallelism

Tags: concurrency, etl, airflow

I was asked to code a more "professional" version of an ETL script. By professional I mean: supervision (logging and email alerts), parallelism, and scheduling. With those goals in mind, I started reading the **Apache Airflow** documentation.

Everything looks great, but I don't know what is the best approach to **parallelism**. The original script starts by downloading a list of object ids. Then, for each id, it makes a query to another endpoint, does some basic computations (generates new fields) and stores the data into a CSV file.

What would be the best approach for doing this in parallel? Dynamically launch a task for each object and joining the data later? Is using XCOM for transferring the data a good idea?
What if there are thousands of objects? Other thing that would be a nice to have, is retrying the query if it fails.

I know I must use the celery executor in this case and spawn a few workers to deal with all the tasks.

Is Apache Airflow the right tool?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this in Airflow. I have a similar situation and my DAG first checks how many objects there are, then uses a basic for loop to create the task(s) for each object. Operators and tasks are uniquely named and assigned for each object. Then the level of parallelism can be controlled by the basic Airflow config options. For connecting everything together at the end, I would be wary of xcoms, as they can take up a lot of db space. You might consider temporarily storing flat files and then merging them to create your final output.